# JQuery FadeIn Specific Div

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to fadeIn a div when a button is hovered over. The code I have so far does this without issues. However, I don't want it to open *every* "div1" on the page, just the one specific to the button being hovered over. It's for Tumblr, so I can't use id instead of class, as it generates the button and div for each entry.

I feel like there is an easy solution to this, but I'm new to jQuery. Thanks for any advice.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button1").hover(function()
{ $(".div1").fadeIn('slow'); 
});
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.div1 {width:80px;height:80px;display:none;
background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;}

.button1 {border:0px;background-color:#d3d3d3;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<p>Sample text.</p>

<button class="button1">Hover here</button>
<br>

<div class="div1">1</div>
<br>

<button class="button1">Hover here</button>
<br>

<div class="div1">2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the selector `$(".div1")`, which will select all the `div1` elements, instead you want to select next to next sibling of the hovered element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button1").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().next(".div1").fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.button1 {
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<p>Sample text.</p>

<button class="button1">Hover here</button>
<br/>
<div class="div1">1</div>
<br>

<button class="button1">Hover here</button>
<br/>

<div class="div1">2</div>
```

Comment: It works perfect now, thanks for your help. I've found jQuery fairly frustrating so far.